# Remove Lucene document by query of not analyzed text field

Tags: java, lucene

I'm 99% sure I had this working in the past, maybe I'm wrong.

Anyway, I'd like to delete a Lucene document by a `Field` which is *stored* but *not analyzed* and contains text.

So the problem, it seems, is that calling `luceneWriter.deleteDocuments(query)` doesn't delete the document unless the field referenced in `query` is `Field.Index.ANALYZED` or a simple number.

Some code:

```
Integer myId = 1234;
Document doc = new Document();
Field field = new Field("MyIdField", myId, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
doc.add(field);
indexWriter.add(doc);
indexWriter.commit();

...

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(VERSION, "MyIdField", ANALYZER);
Query query = parser.parse("MyIdField:1234");
indexWriter.deleteDocuments(query);
indexWriter.commit();
```

Everything works!
Sweet.. what if the field is not analyzed?

```
Field field = new Field("MyIdField", myId, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
```

Still works!
Awesome, what if it's not just a number?

```
Field field = new Field("MyIdField", "ID" + myId, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
...
Query query = parser.parse("MyIdField:ID1234");
```

Doesn't work!.. darn.
The query doesn't match the document and so it isn't deleted.
What if we do index it?

```
Field field = new Field("MyIdField", "ID" + myId, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
...
Query query = parser.parse("MyIdField:ID1234");
```

It works again!

Ok, so if the field is *not analyzed* it can still be queried if it only contains a number? Am I missing something?

Thanks for taking some time.

**Note:**
Technically, there are two fields, making it an `AND` query. As such, I'd prefer to delete the documents with a `Query` rather than a `Term`. I'm not sure if that makes a difference but wanted to emphasize I would like to stick with a solution using a `Query`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745973/search-on-non-analyzed-field-using-lucene), you have to use a `PhraseQuery` to search a not analyzed field. Your code

```
Query query = parser.parse("MyIdField:ID1234");
```

would yield a `TermQuery` instead, and thus won't match.

I recommend you to try a `KeywordAnalyzer` instead (remember that, even if your field isn't analyzed, the query parser could still analyze your query string and therefore your match could fail anyway).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I had a note in my question that I'd like to do this with multiple columns in an `AND` query, which this can't handle. However, I made added a new `Field` in my index so I can use this solution. I think it's better in the long run. Thanks again.